# Error while creating table SQLite Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to run this simple "program"

```
import sqlite3
CIP_InvoiceDB = 'CIP_Invoice.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(CIP_InvoiceDB)
c = conn.cursor
print('Connection opened')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Cliente ( 
                DNI INT PRIMARY KEY,
                Nombre TEXT NOT NULL,
                Apellido TEXT NOT NULL,
                Tipo TEXT DEFAULT 'Cliente') WITHOUT ROWID;
          ''')
print('Table created')
```

And I get this error in the command line when triggering it:

```
Connection opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createDB.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Cliente (
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

What am I doing wrong? Also I don't understand why there is a lot of variations in quotations. I did some research and everywhere I see a create table sentence is inside a triple single quote ('''), Why?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't call the cursor method.

```
c = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used the connection rather than the cursor when doing the executions.